# In JavaFX, How to gradient fill multiple objects on canvas as one object?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to draw three separate round rectangles and then fill all three with a linear gradient, but have the gradient traverse all three objects. I can't seem to find any information on drawing objects onto a canvas and linking them together.

I'm very new at using canvas in general.

Here is what I have so far:

```
final Canvas          canvas  = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
final GraphicsContext gc      = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
double                offset1 = .1;
double                offset2 = .9;
Color                 color1  = Color.rgb(0,0,255);
Color                 color2  = Color.rgb(0,200,255);
Stop[]                stops1  = new Stop[] {new Stop(offset1, color1), new Stop(offset2, color2)};
gc.setFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, .2, 1.4, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops1));
double third = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 3.0;
double thirdM2 = third - 10;
double h2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT - (2 * third);
double h3 = CANVAS_HEIGHT - third;
gc.fillRoundRect(0,0,CANVAS_WIDTH,thirdM2,thirdM2,thirdM2);
gc.fillRoundRect(0,h2,CANVAS_WIDTH,thirdM2,thirdM2,thirdM2);
gc.fillRoundRect(0,h3,CANVAS_WIDTH,thirdM2,thirdM2,thirdM2);
```

This makes an image that looks like this

[image: Text]

However, I need it to end up looking like this:

[image: Text]

Is there any way to accomplish this in JavaFX with canvas?

Thank you,

Mike Sims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are a couple ways to do this.  You could render all three rounded rectangles as a single path (using path rendering instead of fillRoundedRect, e.g. moveTo, arcTo etc.), or you could change the render blend mode to SRC_ATOP and paint a rectangle over all three rounded rects.  That's what I've done in the code below:

```
    final Canvas          canvas  = new Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    final GraphicsContext gc      = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    double                offset1 = .5;
    double                offset2 = .9;
    Color                 color1  = Color.rgb(0,0,255);
    Color                 color2  = Color.rgb(0,200,255);
    Stop[]                stops1  = new Stop[] {new Stop(offset1, color1), new Stop(offset2, color2)};
    double third = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 3.0;
    double thirdM2 = third - 10;
    double h2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT - (2 * third);
    double h3 = CANVAS_HEIGHT - third;

    gc.fillRoundRect(0,0,CANVAS_WIDTH,thirdM2,thirdM2,thirdM2);
    gc.fillRoundRect(0,h2,CANVAS_WIDTH,thirdM2,thirdM2,thirdM2);
    gc.fillRoundRect(0,h3,CANVAS_WIDTH,thirdM2,thirdM2,thirdM2);

    gc.setGlobalBlendMode(BlendMode.SRC_ATOP); // preserves the alpha channel set above

    gc.setFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, .6, .5, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops1));
    gc.fillRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, h3+thirdM2);
```

If you don't want to muck around directly on the canvas (because there may be other elements that get in the way that you can't paint over), you can do this trick to a writeable image and then stamp that onto the canvas.

Comment: This is BRILLIANT! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I tested it and it works perfectly!

Comment: I am having one issue. After posting this, I started painting the entire canvas black, then I drew the three round rectangles on top of that so that the background of the image would be black. Now, when I add the three additional lines that you posted, it applies the gradient to the entire canvas.  Is there any way I can do this while making the background either transparent or just straight black?

Comment: Looks like I was able to do it by changing the globalBlendMode a second time to BlendMode.ADD, then painting black, Thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelSims That problem of overwriting the black is what I eluded to when I mentioned doing this to a WritableImage and then just drawing that image to the canvas.  I should have mentioned that to get that image you use another temporary Canvas and take a snapshot.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have been using WriteableImage to convert a canvas over to an Image object. And thanks to your answer here, I decided to experiment with simple graphic icons drawn in Photoshop. I realized I could paint those images onto Canvas, then set globalBlendMode to ADD and then paint those images with gradients or whatever. This gave me the final piece to the puzzle where I am now experimenting with color themes and giving the user the ability to change the appearance of the app.  Thank you again!